# Wordpress : make a plugin to load scripts only if on class name is in an article

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

**I am trying to write a wordpress plugin that would load 2 js files and a stylesheet only if an article has an element with the class .test in it.**

This element is inserted in the article by the editor himself in the article edition page in an acf field where the editor writes html code.

At this point no files are loaded and this doesn't work :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Comparative Div Tables
Plugin URI: https://www.tourdumondiste.com
Description: Mon plugin pour faire des tableaux
Version: 8
Author: François Rosenbaum 
Author URI: https://www.tourdumondiste.com
License: GPL2
*/


function custom_comparative_div_tables_load_script() {
        if (is_singular()) { 
        global $post;
        $content = $post->post_content;

        if (strpos($content, 'test') !== false) {

            wp_enqueue_script('custom-comparative-div-tables', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/custom-comparative-div-tables.min.js', array('jquery'), '8', false);
            wp_enqueue_script('custom-comparative-div-tables-syncscroll', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/syncscroll.js', array(), '8', false);
            wp_enqueue_style('custom-comparative-div-tables-css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/custom-comparative-div-tables.min.css', array(), '8', false);

        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_comparative_div_tables_load_script');
```

This code above seems correct to me. I mean there are no errors in it. But, I suspect that `$content = $post->post_content;` doesn't get the part of the article I need. I believe it doesn't get the content of the ACF fields.
Actually where I want to search for the class .test is in multiple ACF fields of type wysiswyg editor. In these fields my editors write directly in html.

```
This is my ACF fields structure :
"content" : Group field
   > "flexible" : flexible content
      > "chapter" : Layout
         > "paragraphs" : flexible content
            > "one_column" : layout
               > column_1 : wysisyg editor
            > "two_columns " : layout
               > column_1 : wysisyg editor
               > column_2 : wysisyg editor
```

In each article I have multiple ACF wysiwyg editor fields named column_1 and column_2. This where I am looking for my element that has the class .test

*Just in case you wonder :
I am absolutly sure about the urls, the names and the presence of the files where expected. |
wordpress version : 6.2.2 |
php version used : 7.4.25 |
I really dont want to use a shortcode but really detect a class name.*

That would be awesome if you can help ? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: note: if targeting PHP 8+, you should use `str_contains()` instead of `strpos()`

Comment: what is the class you are looking for? please add a HTML snippet that shows exactly what you are getting on the `$content` variable when trying to find it.

Comment: your code is working -are you sure that add class to post?

Comment: Hello @Cornel Raiu, my php version is 7.4.25 and the class I'm targetting in this code is .test. I don't know how to verify the content of the content variable.

Comment: @ayoob zare it also seems to me that this code is correct. I believe there are no errors in it. However it doesn't do what I need. I guess the problem is my $content = $post->post_content; that don't get what I want in the content of my article because what I am looking for is from ACF fields where the editors write in direct html code. I am giving more details in my next answer.

Comment: _"I don't know how to verify the content of the content variable."_ - make a debug output (apply `htmlspecialchars`, otherwise you won't see any HTML it might contain, when outputting this into an HTML context), or check directly in the database. _"the class I'm targetting in this code is .test"_ - although right now, you are only checking for `test` _anywhere_ in the post content, so this would apply even if the user wrote "This is a test!" in the post content.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the meaning of ACF fields is in this, that you mentioned in the last comment - but I am guessing, your post content probably did not get parsed already at this point, so whatever shortcodes, ACF field reference etc. it contains, might still be in there as-is - if so, you should apply the `the_content` filters first, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: @CBroe I believe you're right. My post content probably did not get parsed at this point. That would explain why my code don't look inside the ACF fields for an element with the class .test. You're idea of using this filter seems to be a good idea as the documentation says : "filter used to filter the content of a post after it is retrieved from the database and before it is printed to the screen."
Unfortunatly, it's too advanced coding for me. I don't understand what I should write to get my plugin to look for an element .test in my post content and enqueue a script only if there is one.

Comment: `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);` should get you the post content parsed, and all such "references" such as short tags, ACF fields, etc. resolved; _if_ your code runs "late enough" for all other plugins involved - such as ACF in this case - to have already "done their stuff".

Comment: @CBroe wouldn't it be even better to look inside of all ACF fields of the current post and named column_1 and column_2 and enqueue my scripts if an element with the class test is found ?
I am trying to do that but I don't succeed.

Comment: Sure, you could do that as well. get_field with the post ID to fetch the data structure, and then you'll have to check if what you are looking for is in there.

Comment: @CBroe I tried you're solution by only changing the definition of the $content variable in the code above. I changed  `$content = $post->post_content;` by `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You'll need to do a bit of basic debugging then. You're the one sitting in front of the system with the necessary access ...

Comment: @CBroe well thanks for the help I'm giving up for some time. Hopefully i can find someone that will make this simple plugin for me